# how to multily two fields from two different collections

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, collections, aggregate

I have two colections in mongodb sring boot:

```
public class StampOperation {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private int addedQuantity;
    private int previousQuantity;
    private int remainingQuantity;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date operationDate;

    @DBRef
    private TaxStamp taxStamp;
}


public class TaxStamp 
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private double value;
    private EType stampType;
    private int globalInitialQuantity;
    private int minimumThreshold;

}
```

is there any wa to multiply addedQuantity from StampOperation  by value from TaxStamp ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know, how to multiply two values from two different objects.

```
    double result = stampOperation.addedQuantity * taxStamp.value;
```

To do this operation, you need to have the referenced instances of both classes at hand. Also, the attributes which are supposed to be used (addedQuantity and value) need to be accessible. This could be done by e.g. marking them as public.

Comment: thanks a lot to answer so fast but i can't understand what do you mean by "you need to have the referenced instances of both classes at hand"